# How to show another URL in wordpress web page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change a URL of WordPress portfolio item as a normal URL. Like `http://example.com/portfolio-item/example` as `http://example.com/example`.

Answer (score 0):

First, we will remove the slug from the permalink

```
function portfolio_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'portfolio' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

   $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'portfolio_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Just removing the slug isn't enough. Right now, you'll get a 404 page because WordPress only expects posts and pages to behave this way. You'll also need to add the following:

```
function portfolio_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portfolio', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'portfolio_parse_request' );
```

Just change **"portfolio"** to your custom post type. You may need to refresh your permalinks.